# Bootstrap for Fleiss' K reliability

Tags: r, bootstrap, reliability, resampling

I have a dataset with 5 raters and 129 nominal observations.

I want to calculate Fleiss'K for inter-rater reliability and I need to use bootstrap to calculate the Confidence Intervals. I am using R

Let this be our dataset

```
# Set the number of raters and observations
num_raters <- 5
num_observations <- 130

# Generate random "Red" or "Blue" for each observation and rater
set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
random_data <- matrix(sample(c("Red", "Blue"), num_raters * num_observations, replace = TRUE), nrow = num_observations, ncol = num_raters)

# Print the resulting matrix
print(random_data)
```

I am calculating Fleiss' K for my dataset as follows

```
library("irr")
#Fleiss K
kappam.fleiss(data)
```

Now I want to use bootstrapping to calculate Fleiss' K of 1000 datasets obtained through a resampling of my original dataset.

I am really struggling to do so, can anyone help?